# Mysql query and some help on select statment

Tags: php, mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

```
SELECT SHA2('abc', 256);
```

when I run this one I get the output as encrypted sha2 of the abc 
and also it work fine to insert it on DB 
how to select abc as a normal value like

```
abc >> sha256
```

but when I select I get Decrypted or real value which is abc

`SELECT sha2_decrypt` or what is the correct to be written?

Answer (score 2):

SHA2 is a ONE way encryption... While you can always encode 'abc' and get the same encrypted value (for comparison of Is password correct kind of thing)

But you can not Decrypt encrypted String back into 'abc'.

Comment: but look when token generated it send decrypted one to mail and insert  encrypted one to DB when i click the link it confirm the token by compare the decrypted with encrypted so how that can be done ?

Comment: What it is actually doing is encrypting what you want to compare, and taking the encrypted result, and comparing it to the stored encrypted string.  If they match its a pass.. if not its a fail.